# Akka Streams and Java 7

Tags: akka, java-7, akka-stream

What's the correct dependency in sbt file in order to develop Akka Streams Application that can run on JVM 1.7?

Currently I have the following:

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream_2.11" % "2.4.14

Answer (score 4):

Anything since 2.4.0 (included) won't work with Java 7 (see [here](http://akka.io/news/2015/09/30/akka-2.4.0-released.html)).

Last available one would be 2.0.5 experimental (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/0t3u8IAsUcM)).

`"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream-experimental_2.11" % "2.0.5"`